# Email Template goes as Raw Html using Swiftmailer Symfony2

Tags: symfony-2.8

Hi I am sending email templates to email as followas:

//here $emailBody is a twig template with html.

```
$mailBody = $this->templating->render('test/template/layout.html.twig', array(
              'mailBody' => $mailBody
));

$tmp = $this->mailer->createMessage();       
$tmp->setSubject(trim($emailSubject));
$tmp->setFrom('test@gmail.com');
$tmp->setTo($somnerecipeient);
$tmp->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html'); 
$sent = $this->mailer->send($tmp);
```

So when I am geting email my inbox its comes like raw html.Even content-type is already set text/html as:

```
$tmp->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html');
```

What could be the issue, Please assist

Thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `renderView` and you spelled the content as `$mailBody` instead of `$emailBody`. So change like so:

```
$emailBody = $this->templating->renderView('test/template/layout.html.twig', array(
          'mailBody' => $mailBody
));
```

Can you try that and see if it resolves the issue.